# How to set the default configuration for t5/core/datefield back in Tapestry webapp

Tags: tapestry

As I found out that the Latest Tapestry5-jquery 4.1.2 overrides the core datefield via in its Module class.

```
@Contribute(ModuleManager.class)
    public static void setupComponentsShims(
            MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration,
            @Inject @Path("/META-INF/modules/tjq/datefield.js") Resource datefield,
            @Inject @Path("${jquery.assets.root}/vendor/jquery.mousewheel.js") Resource jquerymousewheel,
            @Symbol(JQuerySymbolConstants.ADD_MOUSEWHEEL_EVENT) boolean mouseWheelIncluded) {

        **configuration.add("t5/core/datefield",
        new JavaScriptModuleConfiguration(datefield));**

        if (mouseWheelIncluded)
            configuration.add("vendor/jquerymousewheel",
                    new JavaScriptModuleConfiguration(jquerymousewheel)
                            .dependsOn("jquery"));
    }
```

I still wants to use the default one from tapestry core.
How can I set it back in my web-app which is using the Tapestry5-jquery library also ?? For now i did modify the Tapestry-jquery lib code but there should an easier way rather than modifying the external lib code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see that override in the `JQueryModule` is done by using [mapped configuration](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html#TapestryIoCConfiguration-MappedConfigurations) to the `ModuleManager` service.

As with other contributions you can override this one with `configuration.override(...)`, i.e.:

```
@Contribute(ModuleManager.class)
public void useCoreDateField(
        MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration,
        AssetSource assetSource)
{
    // Load core javascript for the component
    Resource dateField = assetSource.resourceForPath(
        "/META-INF/modules/t5/core/datefield.js");

    // Override the contribution
    configuration.override("t5/core/datefield",
        new JavaScriptModuleConfiguration(dateField));
}
```

Don't forget to clear the browser cache after you do this.